# Read all files residing in S3 bucket inside hadoop reducer program from Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

I am new to Amazon EMR. I want get a list of all files from my input directory and read them in a loop inside my hadoop reducer program. In my local machine the following code is working perfectly on hadoop (with input files in HDFS). But when I am deploying this code on Amazon EMR (with input files in s3 bucket), it fails giving the reason as unknown. I have tried setting the path as `s3://<bucket_name>/<input_dir>` in the `valPath` variable, but it didn't work.

```
Path valPath=new Path("hdfs:/input/" + dirName);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
FileStatus[] valFilePathList = fs.listStatus(valPath);
for (FileStatus file : valFilePathList) {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(file.getPath())));
    String line=br.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        <do something>
        line=br.readLine();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of accessing all the files located in s3 bucket inside my reducer program for EMR?

*UPDATE*: I solved the issue by making few changes to the above snippet.

```
Path valPath=new Path("/input/<dirName>"); // Provide relative path
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("s3://<bucket-name>"), context.getConfiguration()); // Pass the URI of bucket here
FileStatus[] valFilePathList = fs.listStatus(valPath); // Same as above
```

Comment: Hi @Dipankar Ghosh, did you resolve this problem? If so, please update it as your answer.

Comment: Hi @AlexRajKaliamoorthy, kindly check my update above and tell me if it helps.